# Integrate Continuum, Maven and Git (github)

Tags: java, maven, github, continuous-integration, continuum

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now and still can't make this integration happen. I'm probabilly missing something really simple here and got confused along the way!

What I'm trying to do is:

1 - Host the project on github.

2 - Have Continuum watch this repo and clone it every one in a while.

3 - Have Continuum call Maven to build the cloned repo to check for bugs.

How can I make this happen?

If the flow I'm trying to achieve is wrong, please tell me what would be the best way to get these 3 tools running together. :)

Comment: Well, at this point I gave up and switched to svn, which had some troubles at first but were easily solved. I don't know if I'll keep trying to do it using git just to answer this question. But if anyone wants me to explain how I used svn instead of git, just comment here. Thanks.